# Why is this view not found?

Tags: android, listview, view, findviewbyid

I've got a list view with a custom adapter. In the list view are different elements with different XML layouts. One of them is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myapp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    

    <include layout="@layout/list_row_top" />

    <antistatic.spinnerwheel.WheelHorizontalView 
        android:id="@+id/wP_pollrate"
        app:visibleItems="4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the adapter i have the getView method which looks like this:

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    ConfigItem c = configItems.get(position);

    if(c instanceof ConfigFilePicker) {
      if (v == null) {
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_config_picker, null);
      }      
      TextView topLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tV_list_row_top_label);
      TextView configFileName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tV_list_row_config);

      topLabel.setText(c.getTopLabel());
      configFileName.setText(((ConfigFilePicker) c).getChoosenFileName());
    }

    else if(c instanceof ConfigPollrate) {
      if (v == null) {
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);       
         v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_config_pollrate, null);
      }
      TextView topLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tV_list_row_top_label);
      topLabel.setText(c.getTopLabel());      

      /** Setting adapter for picker wheel */
      AbstractWheel wheel = (AbstractWheel) v.findViewById(R.id.wP_wheel);
      ArrayWheelAdapter<String> wheelAdapter =
          new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this.appContext, ((ConfigPollrate) c).getValues());

      /** Setting layout and finally the adapter to the view */
      wheelAdapter.setItemResource(R.layout.wheel_text_centered_dark_back);
      wheelAdapter.setItemTextResource(R.id.text);
      wheel.setViewAdapter(pollrateAdapter);

    }

    return v;
  }
```

As you see i am using a special picker wheel called `antistatic.spinnerwheel` from this project [android-spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel).

The problem is that this `AbstractWheel wheel = (AbstractWheel) v.findViewById(R.id.wP_wheel);` always results in a null pointer. The id is found tho'.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use upper case in id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list item views are recycling, so convertView is not null in row 2->x but contains layout inflated in row before. So in case first layout is created at the beginning and then in second row it goes to `else` clause it will crash because layout `list_row_config_picker` doesn't contain AbstractWheel.
Hope you understand what I mean.

You can remove `if (v == null)` check, so layout will be always inflating.

Comment: and how can i avoid recycling for this special element?

Comment: You can remove if (v == null) check. So layout will be always inflating.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seem to be the solution but now i ran into another error. Let me get around this one and then i will mark your answer. Thank you very very very much and have a nice day.

Comment: '07-19 23:16:42.658: E/AndroidRuntime(5135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 23:16:42.658: E/AndroidRuntime(5135): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0'
....
'07-19 23:16:42.658: E/AndroidRuntime(5135):  at antistatic.spinnerwheel.AbstractWheel.onLayout(AbstractWheel.java:445)'

Comment: I left some messages out to match the maximum allowed characters. The error belongs to the spinnerwheel i've mentioned before. But i almost copied it from the example which is working ok.

Comment: I was debugging and saw that the wheel is now found. So you definitely solved my first problem. You really helped me out. Thanks alot.

Comment: Try set width and height in xml for AbstractWheel. Maybe there is problem with AbstractWheel in onLayout when is width and height set to wrap_content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33809/discussion-between-user1965985-and-koso)